# RxJava2 Convert two Single's into Completable

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I have two Singles, I would like to do is convert these into a Completable

```
 final Single<Boolean> httpRequestOne = createHttpRequestOne();
 final Single<Boolean> httpRequestTwo = createHttpRequestTwo();
```

If both singles return true, the result of the Completable should be onSuccess otherwise it will be onError.

I also want them running in parallel so I was thinking concat wouldn't help here

```
final Flowable<Boolean> flowable = httpRequestOne.concatWith(httpRequestTwo);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the `zip` operator, so that you can:

- Combine the result of the two operations
- Parallelize the work (subscribing to different schedulers)

and eventually you can translate the two results into a single result that you want (in your case it is just a logic AND).

```
private Completable createCompletable() {
        return Single.zip(createHttpRequestOne().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()),
                createHttpRequestTwo().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()), (b1, b2) -> b1 && b2)
                .flatMap(new Function<Boolean, SingleSource<Boolean>>() {
                    @Override
                    public SingleSource<Boolean> apply(@NonNull Boolean aBoolean) throws Exception {
                        if (aBoolean) {
                            return Single.just(true);
                        } else {
                            return Single.error(new Throwable("one of the Single returned FALSE"));
                        }
                    }
                }).toCompletable();
    }
```

And then subscribe to it:

```
createCompletable()
     .subscribe(() -> logd("onCompelte"),
                throwable -> logd("error: " + throwable.getMessage()));
```

If both `Single` complete emitting TRUE, `onComplete` will be emitted from your completable, otherwise you will get an error, and the `onError` will be triggered in your subscription.

Comment: toCompletable() is depricated

Comment: @IvanVovk 2 years ago it wasn't. Now it is! You should use `ignoreElement()` now.